# Why setUrl doesn't update the url in my form component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, react-hooks

I build my custom hook(useStorage.js), after uploading the file and getting the url it should update the url in my form component, but it doesn't, instead I get an error when it tries to access the url value but is null.

I've tried to debug it and after calling handlePhotoUpload or handlePdfUpload, it doesn't update the urls(is null).

```
This is the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at ProfileDataForm (profileDataForm.component.jsx:112:37)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
ProfileDataForm @ profileDataForm.component.jsx:112
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
profileDataForm.component.jsx:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at ProfileDataForm (profileDataForm.component.jsx:112:37)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
```

useStorage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { uploadFile, getFileUrl } from "../services/uploadFile";

export function useStorage(){
    //const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);


    const handleUpload = async(file , fileName , folderPath) =>{
        if (file) {
            try {
                const snapshot = await uploadFile(file, fileName , folderPath)
                const url = await getFileUrl(snapshot.ref)
                console.log(url)
                setUrl(url);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error)
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
    return [ url, error , handleUpload ];
};
```

dataForm.jsx

```
import { Grid, TextField, Button, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { MobileDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDatePicker';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import esEsLocale from 'date-fns/locale/es';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { uploadFile } from '../../services/uploadFile';
import { updateDocument } from '../../services/updateDocument';
import { useStorage } from '../../hooks/useStorage';
import { useUpdateUser } from '../../hooks/useUpdateUser';

const userExample = {
    name : "John",
    lastName : "Rock", 
    secondLastName : "Rock",
    codeforcesUsername : "rock12", 
    email : "rock@gmail.con", 
    nickname : "",
    birthdate : new Date(),
    career : "",
    cellphone : "",
    currentSemester:  "",
    github : "",
    facebook : "",
    instagram : "",
    faculty : "",
    omegaup : "",
    generation : 2,
    inscription : false,
    photo : "", //missing
    problemsSolved : null,
    role : "student",
    rules : false, //missing
    team : "",
    inscriptionComprobant : ""
}

const ProfileDataForm = () =>{
    
    const [formValues , setFormValues] = useState(userExample);
    const [ urlPhoto , 
            errorPhoto, handlePhotoUpload]  = useStorage();
    const [ urlPdf, 
            errorPdf, 
            handlePdfUpload]  = useStorage();
    
    const [newDoc , errorUser , handleUserUpdate] = useUpdateUser()

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormValues({
          ...formValues,
          [name]: value,
        });
    };
    
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {photo , inscriptionComprobant} = formValues

        var uid = "e9O4OfTsNRfPITvtcsF97YgMaYT2"

        await handlePhotoUpload(photo , "ejem.jpeg" , "images/userPhotos/")
        await handlePdfUpload(inscriptionComprobant, "ejem.pdf" , "pdfs/inscriptionComprobant/")

        //upload comprobant 
        // uplaod photo
        console.log(urlPhoto)
        console.log(urlPdf)

            if(!errorPhoto && !errorPdf){
            await handleUserUpdate(uid, 
                {
                    ...formValues,
                    photo : urlPhoto,
                    inscriptionComprobant : urlPdf
                }
            ) 
            if(errorUser) console.log(errorUser);
            else setFormValues(newDoc)
        }
    }

    const handleDatePicker = (value) => {
        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            birthdate : value
        })
    }

    const handleOnChangeFile = (e) => {
        const { name, files } = e.target;
        setFormValues({
          ...formValues,
          [name]: files[0],
        });
    }
    // console.log(formValues)
    return(
        <form>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <Grid container spacing={2} >
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField 
                id = "name" 
                label = "Nombres" 
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                type = "text" 
                value = {formValues.name} 
                name = "name" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "lastName" 
                label = "Primer Apellido"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                type = "text" 
                value = {formValues.lastName} 
                name = "lastName" 
                required/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "secondLastName" 
                label = "Segundo Apellido"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                type = "text" 
                value = {formValues.secondLastName} 
                name = "secondLastName" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <TextField id = "nickName" 
                label = "Apodo"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.nickname} 
                name = "nickname" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={5}>
                <TextField id = "email" 
                label = "Correo"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                type= "email" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.email} 
                name = "email" 
                required/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "cellphone" 
                label = "Número Celular"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.cellphone} 
                name = "cellphone" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale = {esEsLocale}>
                <MobileDatePicker
                label="Fecha de nacimiento"
                inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                value={formValues.birthdate}
                onChange={handleDatePicker}
                renderInput={(params) => 
                <Grid item xs= {3}>
                    <TextField {...params}  margin = "normal"/>
                </Grid>
                }
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <TextField id = "faculty" 
                label = "Facultad"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.faculty} 
                name = "faculty" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField id = "career" 
                label = "Carrera actual"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.career} 
                name = "career" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <TextField id = "currSemester" 
                label = "Semestre Actual"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.currentSemester} 
                name = "currentSemester" 
                type= "number"
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "codeforcesUsername" 
                label = "Usuario de codeforces"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.codeforcesUsername} 
                name = "codeforcesUsername" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={5}>
                <TextField id = "github" 
                label = "Github"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.github} 
                name = "github" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "facebook" 
                label = "Facebook"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.facebook} 
                name = "facebook" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "instagram" 
                label = "Instagram"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.instagram} 
                name = "instagram" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <TextField id = "omegaup" 
                label = "Omegaup"  
                variant="outlined" 
                fullWidth 
                margin="normal" 
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                value = {formValues.omegaup} 
                name = "omegaup" 
                required />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button variant="contained" component="label" >
                    Subir foto de perfil
                    <input hidden accept="image/*"  type="file" size = "2mb" name = "photo" onChange = {handleOnChangeFile}
                    />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button variant="contained" component="label" >
                    Subir comprobante de inscripcion
                    <input hidden accept="application/pdf"  type="file" size = "5mb" onChange={handleOnChangeFile} 
                    name = "inscriptionComprobant" 
                    />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button variant="contained" onClick = {handleSubmit}>
                    Actualizar
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </form>
    )
}

export default ProfileDataForm
```

Comment: "I get an error" Please edit your question (there's a link right under it for that purpose) to include the exact error message you get. --- "it doesn't" It's really hard to help with this. Keep in mind that we can't see what actually *does* happen, so you'll have to tell us. For example, does the `console.log(url)` or `console.log(error)` run, and (of so) what do they output?

Comment: Hi, now you can se the error.

Comment: Can you highlight *specifically* where `profileDataForm.component.jsx:112:37` is in the code? I suspect it's `value={formValues.name}` of the first `TextField`. From what I can tell `formValues` has valid initial state with a `name` property, but the error is saying `formValues` is null. Searching for `setFormValues` leads me to a likely candidate `setFormValues(newDoc)` in `handleSubmit`. `newDoc` is returned from the `useUpdateUser` hook. Can you add this `useUpdateUser` hook code to your post and also verify its return values so we can see what `newDoc`'s value?